SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0 WHERE 1=0, Error message from Server: Configuration schema is not available
I'm trying to read the data from sample schema from table nation from data-bricks catalog from my local machine via spark but i'm getting this error.
com.databricks.client.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Databricks][JDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: null, Query: SELECT * FROM (SELECT n_nationkey ,n_name ,n_regionkey ,n_comment FROM samples.tpch.nation order by "n_nationkey" limit 50000 offset 0) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0 WHERE 1=0, Error message from Server: Configuration schema is not available
Here is my sample code.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/opt/spark'
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] + '/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
spark_dict = {
  "hostname": "my_hostname",
  "user": "my_user",
  "password": "my_pass",
  "database": "samples",
  "schema": "tpch",
  "driver": "com.databricks.client.jdbc.Driver",
  "url": "jdbc:databricks://host:443/samples;transportMode=http;ssl=1;AuthMech=3;httpPath=httpPath",
  "port": "443",
  "query": "SELECT n_nationkey ,n_name ,n_regionkey ,n_comment FROM samples.tpch.nation order by \"n_nationkey\" limit 50000 offset 0"
}
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("abc")
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/jars/databricks-jdbc-2.6.34.jar")
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(**spark_dict).load()
        
df.show()

Can someone please guide me here how to fix the above error.


com.databricks.client.support.exceptions.GeneralException
[Databricks]JDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: null, Query: SELECT * FROM (SELECT n_nationkey ,n_name ,n_regionkey ,n_comment FROM samples.tpch.nation order by "n_nationkey" limit 50000 offset 0) SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_0 WHERE 1=0, Error message from Server: Configuration schema is not available

The error message indicates there is a problem with accessing the schema or the configuration for accessing the Databricks catalog in your JDBC URL.
In Databricks, you generally do not need to manually configure the JDBC URL to access tables within the Databricks environment when using PySpark.
Instead, you can directly use Spark SQL features to read from the Databricks catalog.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df = spark.sql("SELECT n_nationkey, n_name, n_regionkey, n_comment FROM samples.tpch.nation")
display(df)

Results:
n_nationkey n_name  n_regionkey n_comment
0   ALGERIA 0    haggle. carefully final deposits detect slyly agai
1   ARGENTINA   1   al foxes promise slyly according to the regular accounts. bold requests alon
2   BRAZIL  1   y alongside of the pending deposits. carefully special packages are about the ironic forges. slyly special 
3   CANADA  1   eas hang ironic, silent packages. slyly regular packages are furiously over the tithes. fluffily bold
4   EGYPT   4   y above the carefully unusual theodolites. final dugouts are quickly across the furiously regular d
5   ETHIOPIA    0   ven packages wake quickly. regu
6   FRANCE  3   refully final requests. regular, ironi
7   GERMANY 3   l platelets. regular accounts x-ray: unusual, regular acco
8   INDIA   2   ss excuses cajole slyly across the packages. deposits print aroun
9   INDONESIA   2    slyly express asymptotes. regular deposits haggle slyly. carefully ironic hockey players sleep blithely. carefull
10  IRAN    4   efully alongside of the slyly final dependencies. 

In the above code I am directly using Spark SQL to read from the Databricks catalog

thanks for your answer, but i'm not using the databricks from databricks environment. I'm trying to connect and read from databricks from my local machine via spark. I know that i can get the data with your code from databricks notebook but i want to get the data from databricks catalog from my local machine via spark.
Also how did you created spark session in your shared code?
